# how can we send post request in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I need help in post request in lwc. Also can you help me to post image with rest api, Below is get request

```
fetch('https://skpycloud.free.beeceptor.com', // End point URL
        {
            // Request type
            method: "GET",
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                //         'Name': 'Salesforce',
                //         'BillingStreet': '1 Market Street',
                //         'BillingCity': 'San Francisco',
                //         'BillingState': 'CA'
            }),
            headers: {
                // content type
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // adding your access token 
                "Authorization": "OAuth 00DB0000000EfVQ!AQwAQEiiynMU2EsBcS2PhXSQ6KQTTG.Zr0hlDHTFcGcAPqKQOBNDB0rwyASZK44fqIAVe6GrVNZPsAWJ6iqXLNBfSQ.dqvW1",
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json(); // returning the response in the form of JSON
        })
        .then((jsonResponse) => {

            let objData = {
                From_Currency_Name: '',
                From_Currency_Code: '',
                To_Currency_Name: '',
                To_Currency_Code: '',
                Exchange_Rate: '',
                Last_Refersed: '',
            };

            window.console.log('jsonResponse ===> ' + JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
            // retriving the response data
            let exchangeData = jsonResponse['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'];


        })
        .catch(error => {
            window.console.log('callout error ===> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        })
```

Comment: Where are you getting the image from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i get image from lightning-input (html) and changed it to base64 , now i need to post to rest api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
fetch(
    endpoint,
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: fileBody,
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            contentType: fileContentType
        }
    }
)
```

If your credentials are invalid, then you can use a valid session ID as demonstrated in your original question. Make sure you use the proper values for fileBody and fileContentType. You should ideally not use a Base64 string, but instead the original binary data.

Comment: fetch(
            'https://skpycloud.free.beeceptor.com',
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: encodeURIComponent(this.fileContents),
                //credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    contentType: "application/json",
                }
            }
        )

Comment: can you please check , i added encodeURI in body and what is the contenttype

Comment: @RijwanMohammed That won't work. The body doesn't go in the URI, and you're not using application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The content type must match the file contents. If you're having trouble with a specific API, documentation on that API would be useful.

Comment: is there any limit in LWC to upload file ?

Comment: @RijwanMohammed The only limits are whatever the server limits are.

Comment: And last question , how to show progress bar of uploading image ,i mean where can i take a variable for this.

Comment: fetch(
            'https://anurag.free.beeceptor.com',
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'image': encodeURIComponent(this.fileContents),
                }),
                //credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    contentType: "application/json",
                }
            }
        ).then((response) => {
        }).then((jsonResponse) => {

        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log('callout error ===> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        })

Comment: @RijwanMohammed There isn't such a feature. If you want to track upload progress, use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: can you send me link where i can get it, and is this working in lwc